# Graphic representation of the complex eigenvector of a rotating matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

The eigenvector of the matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$$

is

$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}$$

with its eigenvalue $-i$

$$-i\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-i\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

The question is how to graphically show this vector. The [graphic representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1600170/152225) has the real part in the x-axis and the imaginary part in the y-axis. Yet, we see $-i$ in the x component of the vector. I would like to "see" the eigenvector elongate, or contract, as a result of its multiplication by the eigenvalue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, but it's unclear what exactly you mean by `graphically show this vector`.

A single complex number can be visualized by a vector in the complex plane. Note that the set $\mathbb{C}$ of complex numbers is a **one-dimensional** vector space $\mathbb{C}^1$ over itself (i.e. over $\mathbb{C}$, as a *complex vector space*). So in that sense it's more like a "complex number line" — akin to the real number line $\mathbb{R}$ as a **one-dimensional** vector space $\mathbb{R}^1$ over itself (i.e. over $\mathbb{R}$, as a *real vector space*). We visualize the complex plane as a plane, however, because $\mathbb{C}$ is **two-dimensional** as a *real vector space* over $\mathbb{R}$. And we as humans (at least, the vast majority of us) are much better at visualizing real dimensions, and only up to three of them.

And that's where the problem with your request lies. The space $\mathbb{C}^2$ is **two-dimensional** as a *complex vector space*. But to visualize it as such, we need two "complex number lines", i.e. two Argand planes is the two axes. In reality, we immediately think of each complex coordinate as $z=x+iy$ with two real components, so effectively we're thinking of $\mathbb{C}^2$ as a **four-dimensional** *real vector space*. Representing it geometrically requires drawing in four real dimensions — and there's nothing wrong with that mathematically, except for the fact that for most of us (myself included) it's really difficult to imagine that.

Comment: That stylistic point notwithstanding, is [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring) a possible avenue to represent graphically these eigenvector / eigenvalue combinations? They do work with functions, but I'm not sure about vectors.

Comment: @MathAsFun: The function of the opening sentence is to convey the idea that to us, your readers, it's not clear what exactly you're looking for, so maybe you could clarify what kind of graphical interpretation you're seeking. I kinda assumed that the word "unclear" hints well enough at a desire to see a clarification...

Comment: @MathAsFun: To be honest, I can't see how domain coloring could be applied here, since you only need to plot a single vector, not a function. But I'm not claiming to have the last word here. Maybe somebody else could come up with some ideas?

Comment: @MathAsFun: I guess the point of my answer was: $\mathbb{C}^2$ is just a two-dimensional vector space over the complex numbers. If you only need to visualize it for yourself, to develop your own intuition, you can just think of it the same way as you think of the usual plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ -- where we have vectors with two components. That's what I do. But if providing a graphical representation is a homework task, then there has to be a clarification of what is expected.

Answer (score 1):

As
$$
-i = e^{i3\pi/2}
$$
multiplication by it means rotating the vector by $3\pi/2$ only and no length change.

**Update:**

[image: VectorPlot]
[image: Streamplot]

Or try it yourself: [link](http://sqrt(x%5E2+y%5E2)%20cos(atan2(y,x)+0.5))

Comment: Right, but doesn't this contradict the idea of an eigenvector/eigenvalue pair, i.e. the vector is scaled preserving its orientation? And how do you plot the vector $\begin{bmatrix}-i\\1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @MathAsFun No, there’s no contradiction. In the *complex* vector space $\mathbb C^2$, multiplication by $-i$ is indeed simply scaling the vector without changing its “orientation.” If you’re dealing with a *real* vector space, however, there are no *real* vectors that correspond to complex roots of the characteristic equation. (Strictly speaking, you can’t call the latter eigenvalues of the matrix.) These complex eigenvalues/vectors do, however, let you identify invariant spaces of the transformation.

Comment: Can you plot this?

Comment: @MathAsFun Here are two plots.

Answer (score 0):

I think probably the most straightforward way to plot complex eigenvectors is to draw up two Argand planes, and in the first plane, draw the two (or more, depending on the dimension in involved) complex coordinates of the first vector. Make certain to colour the vectors to distinguish between them (e.g. black for the first coordinate, red for the second coordinate). Then do the same for the image vector on the second Argand plane, keeping the colour scheme the same.

What are you looking for? Well, if we want a parallel vector, we would expect to see a common complex number $re^{i\theta}$ to multiply both complex numbers in the first plane to produce the complex numbers in the second plane. In other words, we expect to see that the second plane is a rotated and scaled version of the first (including preserving orientation between the different vectors).

This is about as visually clear as I think parallel complex vectors can be made.

Comment: Can you produce a picture?

Comment: I'll give it a try. It's not something I typically do, so I don't have the tools on hand.

Comment: @MathAsFun Sorry, I tried, but it's taking too long.